# Mapping one value of a column with nan value of that column depending upon values in other column

Tags: python, pandas

There are two columns UserID and country. In some rows of country there are values but in other there are nan values for the same UserID. I want to map the value of country in the nan values.

```
UserID      Country
1            India
2            US
3            Uk
1            nan
4            nan
2            nan
4            nan
```

Output required:

```
UserID      Country
1            India
2            US
3            Uk
1            India
4            nan
2            US
4            nan
```

I tried doing it this way:

```
df['Country']=df['UserID'].map(lambda x:df[x])
```

but I am getting error for UserID 4.
I tried replacing the country of UserID 4 manually:

```
df['Country']=np.where(df['UserID']==4,'India',df['Country'])
```

but still I am getting an error. What went wrong or is there any other way to approach it?

Comment: *Mapping NaN values [from another column]* is called **filling** NaNs. In your case you want to fill NaNs from (other non-NaN) values in the same groupby 'Country'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try via `groupby()` and `ffill()`:

```
df['Country']=df.groupby('UserID')['Country'].ffill()
```

OR

via `groupby()` and `fillna()`:

```
df['Country']=df.groupby('UserID')['Country'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

Comment: Yes it did but can you say how is it working?

Comment: @shrijoychowdhury yup sure we are grouping by 'id' and forward filling 'Country' column value...at index 0 `user id` is 1 and `Country` is 'India' and at index 3 the user id is 1 but Country is missing so since we are grouping by userid and using ffill() so now country will be filled by 'India' but In case user id 4 there is no row ahead of it so that ffill() method look for value hence it is remain nan and for the last row the previous row where user id is 4 is missing so the last row of your dataframe where user id is 4 is also missing